# How do I define variables that will be set in a script based on where an RPM is installed using setup.py?

Tags: rpm, setup.py

I am trying to set an IP address in a script that will be placed on multiple machines. I am packaging the script in an RPM using setup.py (using the script as the entry point) and the RPM will be installed on these machines using yum. I want the IP address variable to be based on the machine the RPM gets installed on.

Other systems will likely pull the script from the install locations, but I need the IP address to remain as the machine the RPM is installed on.

If this doesn't make sense I'll try to list the steps:

1. `my_script` has `ipaddress` variable that needs to be set as the
   machine it gets installed on
2. `my_script` gets packaged in `my.rpm`
3. `my.rpm` gets installed on machine A using yum causing `my_script`
   to be placed as `/usr/bin/my_script` (at this point `my_script`
   should have IP address written directly into `my_script` and stored
   in `ipaddress`
4. Machine B copies the script over to use

Is there any way to set the variable in the script during install time?

I don't have to use setup.py, I can switch to using a makefile/spec file setup to build the RPM if need be.

Comment: just had a thought -- i could use sed in a post-install script to add the ip address to the file

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to hardcode variable in script. You should store it in config and the script should parse the config.

Then you will have in spec file:

```
Requires(post): gawk
Requires(post): iproute

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/yourconfig
touch %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/yourconfig

%post
ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print "IP="$2}' | cut -f1  -d'/' > /etc/yourconfig 

%files
%config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/yourconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing it in a file, you might want to have it be a script that parses the output of `ip addr list` in some way. Then you can have your "smarts" in one place, and if for some reason the IP changes, you won't need to reinstall the RPM.

Another advantage is you can continue to add smarts to it, e.g. you might want to filter out VM interfaces, home, unroutables, etc.